# Does Paypal block non-account transactions when a Paypal account is closed?

Tags: credit-card, paypal

Some months ago I permanently closed my Paypal account.

Today I tried to pay for something online at a web site using Paypal as its credit card payment provider.  It gave me the option to create a Paypal account; I refused.  I still had to enter my e-mail address and phone number, though.

The transaction was blocked.  I then borrowed my wife's credit card (same bank, slightly different card number) and entered her personal information instead, and it processed successfully.

I haven't had any other problems paying by credit card; I just used it yesterday for a few things.

Does Paypal prevent payments through its service for people who have ever had a Paypal account and then deleted it?

Comment: Sounds likely to be a security feature...  but also sounds like the kind of question that you need to ask PayPal directly

Comment: @keshlam Actually, as I asked them to delete my account, if they denied my payment on the basis of my e-mail address, that strikes me as a _lack_ of security: Why would they still have my e-mail address?

Comment: To make sure nobody else is still trying to use your account? Ask them.

Comment: @keshlam I'm aware that I can ask them, thanks.

Comment: Try from another E-mail address, if you have one? That might help determine whether they are injecting to the user or the credit card.

Comment: That's what I plan to do next time.

Comment: Complain to the vendor.  “I couldn’t buy your product because PayPal rejected it due to me having closed my PayPal account months ago.”  Ask them to complain to PayPal.

Comment: @RonJohn But I don't _know_ that that's why it was rejected, hence the question.  It's not as if it showed a message saying, "Because you closed your Paypal account, we're petulantly denying your credit card charge."  I'm trying to ascertain whether this is a thing Paypal does.  The only data points I have personally are what I described in the question.